# Setcounter in tasks package

Tags: counters, tasks

Is there a way to start with a higher counter within the tasks package.

I tried `counter-format = (tsk[c])` but that did not work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post compilable document examples, not just fragments of code

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how the setting of the counter is possible directly from the `tasks` package code, but perhaps I've overlooked some feature.

Anyway, `tasks` does not really use a traditional counter but is applying the `expl3` `int` variable features. The task number is stored in `\g__tasks_int`, a global variable (but it is actually an internal one, because of the double underscore `__` naming convention), which can be set using `\int_gset:Nn`.

However, this requres switching to `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` and defining a new command, say `\SetTaskNumber`, which can be used right after the `\task` command that should get the new number.

Setting outside of `\begin{tasks}` is not possible, since `tasks` resets the task number.

Be aware, that `tasks` have a `resume` feature -- this might break with this setting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\ShowTaskNumber}{
  \int_use:N \g__tasks_int
}
\newcommand{\SetTaskNumber}[1]{
  \int_gset:Nn \g__tasks_int {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task\SetTaskNumber{5} Foo \ShowTaskNumber
  \task Bar \ShowTaskNumber
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @clemens: Yes, that's true -- it's internal. But I suggest to provide an interface to access the 'counter' value ;-), something like `enumitem` package's `start=...`

Answer (score 1):

Since v1.0 (2019/10/04) `tasks` uses a standard counter named `task`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}[2019/10/04]% v1.0 or newer
\begin{document}

\setcounter{task}{17}
\begin{tasks}[resume](3)
  \task foo \task bar \task baz
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Version 1.1 will also support an option called `start` in order to set the value directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}[2019/11/03]% v1.1 or newer
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[start=18](3)
  \task foo \task bar \task baz
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

with the same output as above.